# Start position and random movement for some divs

Tags: javascript, random

I want to make something similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9agtb339/1/) action, but have the divs start at a random position instead of the top left.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
});

function newDiv() {
    var $div = $("<div class='a'>");
    $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
    animateDiv();



    function animateDiv() {
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        var oldq = $div.offset();
        var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

        $div.animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, speed, function () {
            animateDiv();
        });

    };
}

function makeNewPosition() {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = .4;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

```css
div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animatedDivs"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9agtb339/56/ ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9agtb339/57/

Comment: I've noticed you ask a lot of questions, but you don't give back to the people who help you. Please upvote helpful answers, and mark the answer that answers your question as accepted, so you and them can both earn reputation for the site.

Comment: @FrankerZ - They have asked 4 questions in a year. It's not a big deal, if they don't mark answers, they don't mark answers. You can avoid them next time if you want?

Comment: @Jesse I understand it's not a big deal, hense a one line comment response on a question. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Im sorry, i have to read the policy better, you are right! Thanks a lot Jesse and DontVoteMeDown, im happy with the code only the div's don't show all on the same time, but after a while they are all visible. Any change to fix this? Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've updated the jsfiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9agtb339/58/)

Was simply adding these two lines:

```
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var $div = $("<div class='a'>").css({top: newq[0], left: newq[1]});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
});

function newDiv() {
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var $div = $("<div class='a'>").css({top: newq[0], left: newq[1]});
    $(".animatedDivs").append($div);
    animateDiv();



    function animateDiv() {
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        var oldq = $div.offset();
        var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

        $div.animate({
            top: newq[0],
            left: newq[1]
        }, speed, function () {
            animateDiv();
        });

    };
}

function makeNewPosition() {

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = .4;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

```css
div.a {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animatedDivs"></div>
```

Comment: @Veugerton If this solution works for you, please upvote/mark as the answer so that other users may benefit from this question.